# A word for the fear that everyone can read your mind?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

When I was young, I had an irrational fear that everyone in the world was an actor who could read my mind. This fear was highly specific, and I felt that I was the only one who had it, especially since I couldn't find a word for it on phobia websites. One day I was randomly browsing a small website dedicated to phobias, and I found this exact same fear. I have since forgotten the term for it, though.

Comment: I would call it "Sydney's Syndrome."

Comment: I know what I would call it, but I can read minds and know for a fact Sydney does not know what to call it *and* can't read my mind.

Comment: I love these little quips. Maybe I should migrate here from time to time. Though I'm sure you knew I was going to say this, granted that you can read my mind. :)

Comment: 'Paranoid' or 'child of helicopter parents'

Comment: You might want to include the sites you've already reviewed for your word to help our users help you.

Comment: Two words: *thought broadcasting* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_broadcasting

Comment: Actually, this is a problem for poker players, and the visible manifestation of a player's hand is called a "tell."

Comment: "Thought broadcasting is considered a positive symptom of schizophrenia." How reassuring! :)

Comment: Rickmanophobia...

Comment: [intrusive thoughts?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256971/word-for-that-certain-fear-worrying-you-might-involuntarily-jump-from-a-cliff/256989#256989)

Comment: Maybe what you really want is a name for the fear of not finding a name for your phobia.

Comment: I'm sure this is made up, but *telepathophobia*.

Comment: I did have intrusive thoughts as well. Not sure if they are the same thing. I'll have to look into it more.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A Bingo! Excellent find!

Answer (score 1):

If 'telepathy' is reading minds, and '-pathy' is a suffix indicating disease or disorder, then 'telepathypathy' would be a pathological fear that people can read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Fear of "INDWELLING" may be used.

It could be called "indwelling psychosis".

It might be a new term but may mean a fear of being seen through or someone gaining insight into someone's inner self.

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon is called "thought broadcasting" and is used for people with schizophrenia

Comment: That's the phenomenon, but what is the fear of it called?

Answer (score -3):

Phobia names are generally Greek and Latin so you could work out what the word could be. Psycho for mind, legere for reading, phobia for fear; psycholegerephobia could be a good candidate.

Comment: The setup of Sydney's question indicates that he's asking for an already-existing term, not for newly invented ones put together by us.

Comment: Would you still think that if rather than candidate I had said starting point?

Comment: Also, I understand if you don't agree with the way that I have built the word, but unless you can find another word which proves mine is wrong, I don't feel you have the right to down vote my answer.